# Formatting th:field in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a form input field in Thymeleaf. The field (bookingEntry.datefrom in the code snippet below) is type Date. I use a datepicker to allow the user to select and format the required date to enter the field. This is all fine.

However, I want the initial value of the date (which I have set to the current date) to be displayed in the format that I choose. So, how do I format the date initially shown in a th:field. th:value is ignored (Thymeleaf is getting the value from the backing object, as it should) and I can't seem to apply a format to the th:field.

Thymeleaf code is:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control getdate"
       th:field="*{datefrom}" placeholder="Date From"
       th:value="${#dates.format(bookingEntry.datefrom, 'dd-MMM-yyyy')}"/>
```

I'm sure that I could use a String which is initialise in any format that I choose, rather than a Date type, but I wondered if there was a way to format initial values in a th:field?

Many thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I missed the simple answer, simply because of my limited knowledge of Spring. I'm adding it here incase it helps any other novices like me.
The `@DateTimeFormat` annotation on the element in the object being passed to the form does the job. It ensures that the `Date` object is formatted in the way that you wish (irrespective of whether you are using Thymeleaf or not).

In the example above, within the `bookingEntry` object

```
@Temporal(DATE)
@DateTimeFormat (pattern="dd-MMM-YYYY")
private Date datefrom;
```

Comment: I had missed this solution too.  It also works when I am submitting the thymeleaf form with jquery ajax, and Jackson fails to deserialize the date value to a java.util.Date because of the unsupported default format in Thymeleaf.

Comment: This didn't work for me. When I submit my form with a null value, the form submit parses a null Date but when I submit with a date, matching the style in the DateTimeFormat annotation, I get a 'Bad Request, validation failed' error, status 400.

Comment: worked like a charm after exhausted with many other attempts. BTW pattern should be "MM/d/yyyy" for 03/14/2015 type of date.

Comment: Dude... thank you for this, i feel like a complete idiot now xD

Answer (score 4):

In case your date is null, it will give you error. We have to check the value before we parse the date.

```
<input  type="text" name="date" 
        th:value="${user.dateOfBirth}?${#dates.format(user.dateOfBirth, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}:''" 
        placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"  id="pickyDate"/>
```

Comment: Someone else commented that if you disable the HTML field before submit you don't have to worry for the parsing and it does work.