# Formatting date in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, datetime-format

I'm brand new to Java/Spring/Thymeleaf so please bear with my current level of understanding. I did review [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361691/formatting-thfield-in-thymeleaf), but wasn't able to solve my problem.

I'm trying to get a simplified date instead of the long date format.

```
// DateTimeFormat annotation on the method that's calling the DB to get date.
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-MMM-YYYY")
public Date getReleaseDate() {
    return releaseDate;
}
```

​
html:

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="sprint : ${sprints}">
        <td th:text="${sprint.name}"></td>
        <td th:text="${sprint.releaseDate}"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Current output

```
sprint1 2016-10-04 14:10:42.183
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Bean validation doesn't matter, you should use Thymeleaf formatting:

```
<td th:text="${#dates.format(sprint.releaseDate, 'dd-MMM-yyyy')}"></td>
```

Also make sure your `releaseDate` property is `java.util.Date`.

Output will be like: `04-Oct-2016`

Comment: I'll just leave this here: If you are using LocalDate or LocalDateTime use "temporals" instead of "dates" in Thymeleaf

Comment: Also, if you want to specify a custom Locale, you must reference it as an OGNL expression (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html). eg, `new java.util.Locale('en', 'US')` or `@java.util.Locale@ENGLISH`

Answer (score 24):

If you want to use converters in th:text attributes, you have to use double-bracket syntax.

```
<td th:text="${{sprint.releaseDate}}"></td>
```

(They are automatically applied to th:field attributes)

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#double-bracket-syntax

Comment: Is there a way to configure the format that the double-bracket converter uses?

Comment: @DavidTroyer it works with just about any way you would normally do this -- you can use the `@DateTimeFormat` (just like the question), you can have your `@Configuration` class extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and override addFormatters to add a `Converter<Date, String>`, etc...

Comment: Nice answer for internationalization.  The view is not dependent on the locale.

Comment: Works perfectly with Date, but not with LocalDateTime. Can you help?

Answer (score 18):

If you want show por example = 20-11-2017

You can use:

```
 th:text="${#temporals.format(notice.date,'dd-MM-yyyy')}
```

Comment: Notice - temporals supports only java 8 time api (not standard java.util.Date). In order to use this functionality you need to add `thymeleaf-extras-java8time` dependency.

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` already includes `thymeleaf-extras-java8time`.

Answer (score 3):

you should use Thymeleaf formatting milliseconds

```
<td th:text="${#dates.format(new java.util.Date(transaction.documentDate), 'dd-MMM-yy')}"></td>
```

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the dependencies,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.12.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.12.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

If you will use `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime` or any other class of the new Java 8 Date package, then you should add this additional dependency,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Regarding the type of your date object, if you use `Date`,

```
<td th:text="${#dates.format(sprint.releaseDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')}">30-12-2021 23:59</td>
```

If you use `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime`,

```
<td th:text="${#temporals.format(sprint.releaseDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')}">30-12-2021 23:59</td>
```

***There is still always the option to pass an object of `DateTimeFormatter` in your model properties***

```
// Inside your controller
context.setVariable("df", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"));
// or
model.addAttribute("df", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"));

// Then, in your template
<td th:text="${df.format(sprint.releaseDate)}">30-12-2021 23:59</td>
```

[This article](https://www.baeldung.com/dates-in-thymeleaf) may help you further.

Answer (score 1):

th:text="${#calendars.format(store.someDate(),'dd MMMM yyyy')}"

API : https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#calendars