# Ignore locale on thymeleaf #date.format()

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, locale

I want to keep date format to fix standard regardless of locale. But however it is by default taking current locale and setting format based on locale.

```
th:text="${#dates.format(myDate, 'dd-MMM-yyyy')}"
```

I am always expecting format be like

```
09-Sep-2015
```

but with `CA` locale I am getting `09-de set.-2015`

Is there a way to fix this.

**UPDATE**
This question is not duplicate of [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860643/formatting-date-in-thymeleaf). My problem is related to locale formatting.

Comment: This may be of some assistance - you can try using @Metroids answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860643/formatting-date-in-thymeleaf

Comment: @AmirBll my question is not about formatting. Formatting is working fine. I don't want locale formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure you are using `Maven` or `Gradle`. Add `thymeleaf-extras-java8time` as your dependency.

and instead of `#dates` use `#temporal` and specify `locale` as parameters as below.

```
th:text="${#temporals.format(myDate, 'dd-MMM-yyyy','en')}"
```

But make sure your `myDate` is in `java.time.*` format

Answer (score 0):

The `#temporals.format` function is the correct one to use. However, the third "locale" argument must be a `java.util.Locale` object, not a string.

The following work:

- `#temporals.format(myDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy', new java.util.Locale('en'))`
- `#temporals.format(myDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy', @java.util.Locale@ENGLISH)`

Note that this is true even if you're working with Kotlin Spring Boot. The syntax in the Thymeleaf template isn't Java, it's an OGNL Expression.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html

I'll quote the useful syntax used here:

```
#variable
Context variable reference

@class@method(args)
Static method reference

@class@field
Static field reference

new class(args)
Constructor call
```

Edit: one other option is to specify the Locale in the Thymeleaf context, if you just want to override the default system Locale. I've included a Kotlin snippet of how that might work:

```
val context = Context() // org.thymeleaf.Context
context.locale = Locale.ENGLISH
context.setVariable("x", 0)

templateEngine.process("classpath:template.html", context)
```